# ReadConflictError during long transaction on plone 4.1

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

We have a long request that does a catalog search and then calculates some information and then stores it in another document. Do call is made to index the document after the store.

In the logs we're getting errors such as INFO ZPublisher.Conflict ConflictError at /pooldb/csvExport/runAgent: database conflict error (oid 0x017f1eae, class BTrees.IIBTree.IISet, serial this txn started with 0x03a30beb4659b266 2013-11-27 23:07:16.488370, serial currently committed 0x03a30c0d2ca5b9aa 2013-11-27 23:41:10.464226) (19 conflicts (0 unresolved) since startup at Mon Nov 25 15:59:08 2013)
and the transaction is getting aborted and restarted.

All the documentation I've read says that due to MVVC in ZODB ReadConflicts no longer occur. Since this is written in RestrictedPython putting in a savepoint is not a simple option (but likely my only choice I'm guessing).

Is there another to avoid this conflict? If I need use savepoints, can anyone think of a security reason why I shouldn't whitelist the savepoint transaction method for use in PythonScripts?

Comment: Is that a ReadConflict? Can't it be that the reindexing fails because something else was reindexed while the search + calculation was done?

Comment: You are right. It was getting confused with an earlier ReadConflictError. We're still not sure what is doing the write here but something obviously is

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there really is no way to do a large transaction that involves writes, when there are other small transactions on the same objects at the same time. BTrees are supposed to have some special conflict handling code but it doesn't seem to work in the cases I'm dealing with.

The only way I think to manage this is something like [this code which breaks the reindex into smaller transactions to reduce the chance of a conflict](https://github.com/plone/Products.PloneOrg/blob/master/scripts/catalog_rebuild.py). There really should be something like this built into zope/plone.